# WordPress custom permalink /%postname%.html only applies to posts, not pages?

Tags: wordpress

When I change my permalinks to custom:

```
/%postname%.html
```

My **posts** are all redrawn correctly to post-title.html, however, my **pages** do not get the .html extension (they just appear as if I had used **/%postname%/**.

Anyone know why and what I can do as a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages can have sub-pages, so I guess it makes sense for it to create a directory named after the page.

Is there any reason why you need the `.html`?

Comment: It does make sense to me the way you've explained it. I've got some users asking for .html extensions on their permalinks. They think the site ranks better as .html (for whatever reason :)

Comment: Codex says, "WordPress versions prior to 2.3 lacked canonical URLs, making .html  something very beneficial to add (forcing the URL to be canonical). Now it only provides limited, if any SEO benefits."

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Having_your_posts_end_in_.html